# Save RDD into multiple locations by partitions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How can I save an rdd of `n` partitions into `k <= n` locations?

For instance, if `n=10` and `k=2` I would like 5 partitions (do not care which ones) to go into `s3://bucket/key1` and the other 5 partitions to go to `s3://bucket/key2`.

I'm assuming I need to implement my own `OutputFormat`, is there a way to do it without a custom `OutputFormat`, and if I cannot avoid it, which `OutputFormat` should I extend from?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` or [`MultipleOutputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html)?

Comment: MultipleOutputFormat is close to what I'm looking for, but in my case, the filename does not depend on the records (key or values). I could just hash the keys and mod it by `k` to achieve what I want, but ideally I would like to keep things simple and treat the partitions as a whole rather than introspect into the records.

Answer (score 0):

You should first think about your file output format(avro, binary, text, parquet etc), then you'll probably need to inherit from standard implementation and "play" with paths in your overriden method to achieve your goal of splitting partitions into 2 locations. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: In my case, I just want to `saveAsTextFile` .The different output paths is needed so that a downstream job (not in spark) can fork `k` processes in parallel, each with its own input path == outputs of my spark job

Comment: But can't you define this "split" in downstream job? I mean if you are using some map reduce you usually can define path filter while reading something, so you can define for each of k jobs specific path filter(e.g. in your example first will take only part0 to part5 and second will take part6-part10)
https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/hadoop-filter-input-files-used-for-mapreduce/